# How to output a string containing text surrounded by angle brackets?

Tags: php, echo

I'm trying to echo some variables in this format: `<var1> <var2> <var3> <var4>`.

I tried:

```
echo "<$r[0]> <$r[1]> <$r[2]> <$r[3]>";
```

But it doesn't show any output. How can I make it work?

Comment: It's probably printing fine, but `<>` are used for HTML, so the browser is probably not interpreting them. If you look at the source, you'll see the string printed out as you defined it.

Comment: In addition to what aynber said, if you need `<` and `>` to actually be displayed, replace them with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: Use `htmlspecialchars()` to encode the characters so that the browser doesn't treat them like HTML tags.